# Can't access class member

Tags: javascript, scope

```
function Example(){
     var id;
};

Example.prototype.getId = function(){
     // return this.id; 
};

Example.prototype.init = function(){
   $.post( 'generateId.php', {}, function(data){
       // this.id = data; 
   });   
};
```

How can I access id within these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you think "private" variables exist in Javascript. Private variables are only emulated in Javascript through closures, but do not exist as in other languages. In your code, `id` is only accessible from within your constructor.

You can keep `id` private though, and still be able to access it from within your functions, but you'll have to declare those functions in your constructor as closures to have access to it:

```
function Example()
{
    //private
    var id;

    this.getId = function ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    this.init = function()
    {
       $.post( 'generateId.php', {}, function(data)
       {
           id = data;
       });   
    };
};
```

Another problem is that you're trying to access `this` from within an asynchronous callback. In this context (the callback passed to `$.post`), `this` is whatever the context of the calling function was, which is probably undefined or the XmlHTTPRequest object.

If you want to access it, you'll have to cache the `this` of you function (from your original code, assuming `id` is not private):

```
Example.prototype.init = function()
{
   var self = this;
   $.post( 'generateId.php', {}, function(data)
   {
       self.id = data;
   });   
};
```

Comment: Well, `getId` will return undefined, unless `id` is explicitly set somewhere else. So yes, it's not referencing the same `id` that you declared as private in the constructor.

Comment: Given your code example, `id` is not accessible anywhere except in the constructor. You can get around this by creating closures in the constructor (my first example), but there's no way to access `id` outside of the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your time tjameson, you helped a lot

Comment: If you don't need to support older browsers, you can use `Object.defineProperty(this, "id", {value: data, writable: false})`. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can rewrite a bit:

```
var Example = Example || {};
Example.id = "";

Example.init = function(){
$.post( 'generateId.php', {}, function(data)
{
   Example.id = data; // <-------- error
});  
}
```